# More than 100 of subdomains to be tracked in Analytics using Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, subdomain, analytics, google-tag-manager, multi-subdomains

After searching a lot I still do not have a clear answer on this:
How to implement GAnlaytics for more than 100 subdomains.site.com? 
Each of my subdomains will have Google Tag Manager implemented.
Also I know that the max number of views allowed by google is 25 per domain...

Comment: Why not implement the same code across all subdomains and enable subdomain on the GA config?

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the Property and View limit (50 and 25, respectively), there's no way around that, really, so you'll probably have to break up the sub-d's across several properties. So with that in mind, you could have one GTM container across all sub-d's, and then use a lookup table to determine which data from which sub-d's go into which property. Within the views themselves, for each property, you would need to create a hostname prepend filter so that you know which sub-d you are looking at, as well as a hostname include filter so that you only capture data from a particular sub-d into that view.

You could also have a roll-up view that has data about all your sub-d's under a particular property.

That's the gist of it, so hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot @nyuen. However, so far, I have managed to create filters for my 5 firsts subdomains and this seems working...

Comment: Sorry, please elaborate.